# SQL Performance post virtualization - sp_blitz and latency info attached

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sp-blitz, sp-blitzfirst

[image]Full disclosure, I'm a VMware admin.   We're trying to virtualize a SQL server that handles pricing information for multiple customers.   Up until now, it has been a physical system with local SSDs.   It's now running as a VM,  Win 2016, 128GB memory, 6 vCPU (2sockets, 3 cores) against an all flash array.    I/O has confirmed that this thing screams, storage admin says we're looking at very low latency, which confirms what I/O meter is seeing.

When it was physical, it performed a nightly process where it dumped table contents to a series of txt files per customer, then zipped those files up.   Repeat again for the next customer.

On the physical system, files that are 250MB (text) would take around 6 seconds.   On the VM they're taking around 60 seconds.    I can tell the storage subsytem is in good shape.  I've increased the queue depth for the vhba, and pvscsi controller as per vmware recommendations and no change.

My DBA's are saying "it worked on the physical server just fine, so it must be your system"  If it is, there's no indication on my end that we're saturating the storage connections or running into resource contentions.

I'm attaching my sp_blitz and the subsequent results of the script that shows the wait for the various DBs... one is much higher than others.

[image: sp_blitz]

Comment: You should get more details from the DBAs - what is here isn't really useful for troubleshooting. Get timings and (where applicable) execution plans for each step of the described process and go from there. Have them double check their CPU and memory-related configurations on the instance (guessing this isn't a 1:1 hardware spec of the physical machine) as well.

Comment: Run Crystal Disk Mark on the new drives and compare speeds. See my post here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/01/from-the-server-to-the-san/

Comment: @LowlyDBA - I completely agree.  They haven't been very forthcoming, so i'm trying to put this DBA hat on myself.  They are in Germany, so are one of their many holidays this week and most of next but I'm going to press them shortly.

Comment: @ErikDarling - I believe that looks for physically attached disks.   Not pulling any disks when ran on my server.

Comment: @ErikDarling - I feel I'm missing something, as your demo in the blog is done via a VM.  *digs into documentation*

Comment: No, it should pick up any attached volumes. You can try diskspd as an alternative, but it's not as friendly.

Comment: I couldn't get it to recognize the volumes at all -- I did get I/O Meter to show me, for a 8 worker, 25% read, random load... 16k packet size, average write latency is .5 ms.   I can certainly get more information on the actual steps and commands in the overnight data dump process next week.

Comment: I just figure that these questions should be answered for a more complete view of the situation (1) How much memory was on the original server?, (2) What other VMs share the physical server, and how active are they? (3) What are your current wait states looking like - specifically, I/O related?  Latency isn't everything on a VM - the share of the actual server time available for the VM, and any network / disk connections load that can slow transmissions related to the dedicated machine is also a consideration.  ZIP processes can especially be slowed when the VM's machine is heavily loaded.

Comment: Turn on the Query Store, and you can track the resource consumption, and wait statistics on a per-query basis: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017  And if you can, run the same IO tests on the physical server.  Local flash can be very different from remote flash.

Comment: Thanks all.  I'm going to look into turning on the query store this week.   Hopefully the DBAs will be amenable to walking me through the queries so I can get a better understanding of the latency and the read write processes.